react-big-calendar onSelectSlot returns last day of the week only in production
I am using react-big-calendar and when i select a empty slot using onSelectSlot it return the the end date in calendar.for eg: if the visible dates are from sunday to saturday it always return saturdays date even if the selected slot is from monday and this only happens in production.
Ref: I have selected 11-May 1:00 to 1:30 but it returns 18-May's 1:00 to 1:30 as shown in image
I want the onSelectSlot to return the date which is selected instead of last day in the week.

Issue occured due to changes in packages. Issue resolved after changing the version to 1.12..
